# Getting a value on a different .js file on a blade.php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, variables

My issue is `const SELECTED_CATEGORY_ID`

I have these sets of scripts in my `index.blade.php` in my laravel:

```
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const PROFILE_NON_BBR_EXTERNAL_ROUTE = "{{ route('non-bbr-external') }}";
        const BBR_GROUP_NAME = "{{ route('bbr-group-configuration-all') }}";
        const DATATABLE = "{{ route('bbr-category-configuration-datatable') }}";
        const SELECTED_CATEGORY_ID = data.category_id;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/sweetalert.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('/modules/bbr-category-configuration/js/app.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

in the last script: `app.js`, there is a value inside a button that I need to retrieve which is:

```
 value="${row.category_id}"
```

below is the full output for a bit of context.

```
let TABLE = $('#categoryList').DataTable({
  columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id', width: '10%', orderable: false, searchable: false,
                render: (data, type, row) =>{
                    let html = "";
                    if(row.category_name && row.category_name.toUpperCase() !== "GENERAL"){

                        html += `<ul class="list-inline no-margin">`;
                            html += `<li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <button type="button" value="${row.category_id}" id="edit_category" class="edit_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button>
                                     </li>`;
    
                        html += `</ul>`;
                    }

                    return html;
                }
            }
});
```

What do I need to use in order to retrieve that data from app.js? Using this one will just get me `DATATABLE is not defined` error:

```
const SELECTED_CATEGORY_ID = data.category_id;
```

[image: 1]

UPDATE:

- question, what will I need to do to get the variable from app.js and onto my const?

Comment: That line can't produce the error "DATATABLE is not defined", since DATATABLE is not in it. But ar you trying to put a dynamic value inside a constant??

Comment: the error on that line is `data is not defined`, the other error is coming from another line. make sure the `data` variable is defined before the line. Same for DATATABLE .

Comment: thats my issue, im not sure why DATATABLE is not defined even if it is in app.js